# How do I calculate force from collision between 2 rigidbodies in 2D?

Tags: collision-resolution, rts, physics

I have a physics engine based on the **Game Physics Engine Development** by Ian Millington. In chapter 7.1.1, it provides the formula:

V = (pA.Velocity - pB.Velocity) * (pA - pB).normalized

where V is the resulting closing velocity and pA and pB are the colliding bodies, and the * operator is multiplication between the values of the same position in the vector(i.e. vA * vB = new vector (vA.x * vB.x, vA.y * vB.y).

This work only if the normalized unit vector direction has both positive values.

I'm also having trouble with getting units to not apply extreme amount of force when a unit is inside another, for example, when spawning 2 units on the same position. I'd like to have the effect SC2 has when 2 units overlap where they shift apart from each other instead of pushing each other very far away.

Currently, I have mass and velocity implemented for my rigidbodies and applying a force modifies the velocity by force/mass.

In summary, what I'm asking is how do I resolve collisions in a semi-realistic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misinterpreted the formula.

You should review the *Section 2.1.7 - The Scalar Product*. The dot (·) represents a dot product (or scalar product (please use one of these terms because it's what it is)).

The scalar product is defined like this: with vectors a and b, and scalar value s,

s = a · b = a<sub>x</sub>b<sub>x</sub> + a<sub>y</sub>b<sub>y</sub>

And, as defined, it gives a scalar, not a vector.

---

The 'explosion' you see when two units spawn at the same location is a normal behaviour with collision engines.

To try to avoid this situation, you can try and limit the maximum distance each unit can travel each frame.

---

**Edit:**

I'm not sure you'd want to write a whole physics engine from scratch, as it's one of the most complex parts of a game. I would suggest you to learn and use one that is already written for your target platform if you need that. Re-writing the wheel is often a waste of time when it's not required.

You can take a look [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769) to find one that *seems* like a good start.

You have only vaguely stated your requirements so the question *how do I resolve collisions in a semi-realistic way?* is too vague to be given a good answer.

Comment: Using the scalar product (or anything at all), how can I find the forces to apply to the colliding objects?

Comment: @JPtheK9 I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, I do need to rewrite the wheel with fixed-point math for cross platform determinism.